# Can not submit VAT Return to https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/organisations/vat/{vrn}/returns

Tags: php, curl

According to https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/api/service/vat-api/1.0/oas/page#tag/organisations/operation/SubmitVATreturnforperiod trying to submit VAT Return.

Below is the part of code that submits data.

```
$vrn = 'test';
$endpoint = 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/organisations/vat/'.$vrn.'/returns'; 
$periodKey = 'A001';
$authToken = $access_token;// it is $token_data['access_token']

$vatReturnData = json_encode([
"periodKey" => $periodKey,
"vatDueSales" => 105.5,
"vatDueAcquisitions" => -100.45,
"totalVatDue" => 5.05,
"vatReclaimedCurrPeriod" => 105.15,
"netVatDue" => 100.1,
"totalValueSalesExVAT" => 300,
"totalValuePurchasesExVAT" => 300,
"totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT" => 3000,
"totalAcquisitionsExVAT" => 3000,
"finalised" => true
]);

$vatReturnJson = json_encode($vatReturnData);

$headers = [
'Accept: application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json',
'Authorization: Bearer ' . $authToken, 
'Content-Type: application/json', 
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($vatReturnJson)
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vatReturnData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) {
echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch). ' '. show_line_number();
} else {
echo 'Response: ' . $response. ' '. show_line_number();
}
curl_close($ch);
```

After i give permission in HMRC, something executes in background for ~ one minute, then redirect to my website and i see Error: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer 125

What may be wrong with my code?

After correction

```
$vatReturnData = array(
"periodKey" => $periodKey,
"vatDueSales" => 105.5,
"vatDueAcquisitions" => -100.45,
"totalVatDue" => 5.05,
...
);
```

got `Response: {"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message":"An internal server error occurred"}`.

Comment: have you noticed that you are encoding two times the same array as json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you build an array in PHP

```
$vatReturnData = array(
"periodKey" => $periodKey,
"vatDueSales" => 105.5,
"vatDueAcquisitions" => -100.45,
"totalVatDue" => 5.05,
"vatReclaimedCurrPeriod" => 105.15,
"netVatDue" => 100.1,
"totalValueSalesExVAT" => 300,
"totalValuePurchasesExVAT" => 300,
"totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT" => 3000,
"totalAcquisitionsExVAT" => 3000,
"finalised" => true
);
```

Then you convert the array in a JSON format:

```
$vatReturnJson = json_encode($vatReturnData);
```

You are using json encode twice and that will produce a not valid json to be sent

Comment: Thanks! i corrected, but in such case get Response: {"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message":"An internal server error occurred"}

Comment: the JSON you provided has been processed by the endpoint but this was unable to process it at all. You are probably sending over data that are not in the expected format